# TestBench for Bitwise Operators

Tags: vhdl

Can someone help me to create a TestBench Program for the below Program, please?

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  

entity bitwise is 
  port( a,b    : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);  
        result1, result2, result3, result4, result5, result6 : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)); 
end bitwise;  

architecture arch of bitwise is 
begin  
  result1   <= a and b; 
  result2   <= a or b;
  result3   <= a xor b;
  result4   <= not a;
  result5   <= to_stdlogicvector(to_bitvector(a) sll 1);
  result6   <= to_stdlogicvector(to_bitvector(a) srl 1);
end arch;
```

My Test Bench Program is below: I am stuck to in the Stimulus process where we have to test each and every possibility. It could be either a loop version or just testing possible numbers for each operator.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

  entity test_bitwise is
     end test_bitwise;

  architecture behavior of test_bitwise is
    component bitwise;
       port( a,b    : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);  
        result1, result2, result3, result4 : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)); 
    end component;

    --INPUTS
    signal tb_a  : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := (others => '0');
     `signal tb_b  : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    --OUTPUTS
   signal tb_result1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     signal tb_result2 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     signal tb_result3 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     signal tb_result4 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  

    begin
      -- INSTANTIATE THE UNIT UNDER TEST (UUT)
      U1_Test : entity work.test_bitwise(behavioral)
        port map (a         => tb_a,
                  b             => tb_b,
                              result1   <= tb_result1,
                              result2   <= tb_result2,
                              result3   <= tb_result3,
                              result4   <= tb_result4);

              --STIMULUS PROCESS
                stim_proc : process
      begin

        -- CODE HERE

            end process;
    end behavior;
```

Comment: Looks like a school assignment to me. What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried writing one yourself?  What are the problems?

Comment: @Tricky Not yet but I was thinking whether I should do a loop or just put some random numbers since there are so many inputs. But since I wrote all the operators in the same file I am not sure how to start the middle part

Comment: This seems like a functional coverage problem, look up OSVVM or UVVM and that should help :) might also make it easier

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated in the comments, you should provide some input yourself. What have you tried and why didn't it succeed? If you have hard time to find out what to try and how to start, you could begin by doing the following. And if you don't succeed, you can then edit your question or post a new one so the other members can help you.

Use a for loop to iterate over each and every possibility. Writing all the possible values to test by hand would be exhausting.

1. Because you have two inputs, use two nested `for` loops inside your process. One iterates the values for input `a` and the other one for `b`. [Check here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/for_loop.html) how a for loop is written.
2. Inside the loops, assign values to your signals `tb_a` and `tb_b`. The loop indices are integers, so you have to convert them to `std_logic_vector` type before assigning. [Check here](http://www.bitweenie.com/listings/vhdl-type-conversion/) for a short tutorial about VHDL conversions.
3. Add some delay after each iteration with `wait`.
4. Print the output values for example to simulator console with `report`, or you can even use `assert` statement.